# How to port the local development to a shared web server

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I've done some development on my local using liferay 6.2, Apache Tomcat server using Java 7.

I am provided with a shared web server where i can see java 6 is installed.

I am doing this for the first time, Can some1 please provide any relevant help for porting my local application to this web server?

My target is to make sure the code which is accessible to me by `localhost:8080` should now be available by `url-of-the-web-server:8080`

So far, I have copied my liferay folder on the web server. When I am trying to run the startup.sh file using putty, it just gives this -

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/user/liferay/tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/user/liferay/tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/user/liferay/tomcat-7.0.42/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_37
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/user/liferay/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/user/liferay/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

I am not able to access anything using `http://url-of-the-web-server:8080`